# Chofetz Chaim and Eretz Israel

Tags: eretz-yisrael, lashon-hara-slander, chofetz-chaim

Does the Chofetz Chaim writes about the prohibition of speaking Lashon Hara about Eretz Israel?

Comment: What specifically are you looking for? The Torah writes about it by there meraglim. Are you looking for specific examples?

Comment: I understand the question as whether the CC writes (in his books on Lashon Hara) *specifically* about lashon hara re EY